# How to add set of vms to Multiple resource group in batch of 10

Tags: azure, powershell

I want to create 30 different vm's in 3 Resource Groups. So the First RG needs to have 10, second RG the next 10, and third RG the remaining 10.I have 30 names. But Just need a way where after 10 records get processed the 11 start in the next resourcegroup.

```
#connect-AzAccount
$resourceGroupName = @('Rg1','Rg2','Rg3')
$vname = @('vm1','vm2','vm3','vm4','vm5'...)
$count =0
foreach($vm in $vname){

New-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $res -Name $vm
       
    $count++

    if($count -eq 10){
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Use an array of Resource Groups and a counter that increments each time you create a VM. For each counter mod 10 -eq 0 and counter -neq 0, increment the index of the ResourceGroup array. BTW.. what have you tried so far?

Comment: Have added the snippet

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will help ... as mentioned in my comment, you can use the `modulus (%)` method to move on to the next index of `ResourceGroupName` array when you hit a multiple of 10.

```
$resourceGroupName = @('Rg1','Rg2','Rg3')
$vname = 1..30 | % { "VM$_" } # Using loop to create the VMName for demo here
$count = 0
$rgCount = 0

foreach($vm in $vname){
       
    $count++

    ## You can fill in what you are looking to here.

    Write-Output "$vm created in $($resourceGroupName[$rgCount])"
    
    if($count % 10 -eq 0 -and $count -ne 0 -and $count -lt $vname.Count){
        Write-Output "Resource Group set to: $($resourceGroupName[++$rgCount])"
    }
}

// Prints:
VM1 created in Rg1
VM2 created in Rg1
~... removed for berevity
VM10 created in Rg1
Resource Group set to: Rg2
VM11 created in Rg2
VM12 created in Rg2
~... removed for berevity
VM20 created in Rg2
Resource Group set to: Rg3
VM21 created in Rg3
VM22 created in Rg3
~... removed for berevity
VM30 created in Rg3
```